# math-classes: Prove that Munit is its own negation

Tags: math, typeclass, coq

I've just begun playing around with the math-classes library and I'd would like to prove the following lemma:

```
Require Import
    MathClasses.interfaces.abstract_algebra MathClasses.interfaces.vectorspace MathClasses.interfaces.canonical_names. 

Lemma Munit_is_its_own_negation `{Module R M} : Munit = - Munit.
```

I was planning to prove this like so:

1. Add Munit to the right side using `right_identity`: `Munit = - Munit & Munit`
2. Use `left_inverse` on the right side: `Munit = Munit`
3. Use `reflexivity`.

However, when I try to apply `rewrite <- right_inverse`, I get the following error:

```
Error:
Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
In environment:
R : Type
M : Type
Re : Equiv R
Rplus : Plus R
Rmult : Mult R
Rzero : Zero R
Rone : One R
Rnegate : Negate R
Me : Equiv M
Mop : SgOp M
Munit : MonUnit M
Mnegate : Negate M
sm : ScalarMult R M
H : Module R M

?A : "Type"

?B : "Type"

?H : "Equiv (MonUnit M)"

?op : "?A → ?B → MonUnit M"

?inv : "?A → ?B"

?RightInverse : "RightInverse ?op ?inv Munit"
```

Why is Coq looking for an `Equiv (MonUnit M)` rather than just an `Equiv M` or `MonUnit M`, which are in the environment? Is it possible to complete this proof? If so, how?

Comment: Just a tip: there is a concise way to import all the modules you need: `From MathClasses.interfaces
Require Import abstract_algebra vectorspace canonical_names.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Munit` is an instance of the parameterized `MonUnit` typeclass. That means `Munit` is essentially a record (with exactly one field -- `mon_unit`), but I think you'd like to have your statement about the unit element of type `M`, since it doesn't make much sense to negate a record usually.

I believe it's possible, in principle, to make Coq unpack `Munit` and do the right thing, but why struggle if we can just restate the lemma:

```
Lemma mon_unit_is_its_own_negation `{Module R M} :
  mon_unit = - mon_unit.
```

Then everything goes just as you've described:

```
Proof.
  rewrite <- (right_identity (- mon_unit)).
  now rewrite left_inverse.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the records vs. fields, that's been tripping me up in other places as well!

Comment: That fact is indeed very useful to keep in mind working with typeclasses in Coq. Happy hacking!

Comment: One other quick question - I see that using `now` avoids a use of `reflexivity`. How does that work? I can't seem to find it in [the Ltac reference](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/general-index.html).

Comment: `now` is defined in `Coq.Init.Tactics` like this: `Tactic Notation "now" tactic(t) := t; easy.` And `easy` always can solve a goal if it can be solved by `reflexivity`. `easy` is kind of `auto` little sibling, but can sometimes solve something that `auto` cannot.